# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource not found'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework and I am trying to build a small website using it. So to build CMS I found one source code that is on Apress website of author [Forrest Lyman](http://www.apress.com/9781430218791). I also got the book from local market.

I wanted to have admin module separately so I have created admin module but I got problem in that I am not able to access controller other than IndexController. When I try to access other controller in admin module I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'category' not found' in C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Acl.php:365 Stack trace: #0 C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Acl.php(846): Zend_Acl->get('category') #1 C:\Server\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\cms\library\CMS\Controller\Plugin\Acl.php(52): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('administrator', 'category', 'index') #2 C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php(309): CMS_Controller_Plugin_Acl->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)) #3 C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(941): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)) #4 C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #5 C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #6 in C:\Server\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

After making a controller, I have to add resources in Acl.php file which is located in (library/CMS/Controller/Plugin/).
Just add this in add resources section

```
 $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('category'));
```

Then you can access it.

Thanks.